# How to get JSON entry from returned objects

Tags: javascript, json

I got JSON data, like:

```
{ 
  "id": 1,
  "active": true,
  "dependency": [
        { "id": 2 }
        { "id": 3 }
   ]
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "active": true
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "active": true
}
```

I want to retrieve the "active" value for each dependency in the `id 1` object. So far I used a forEach to get those dependency.

```
thisElement.dependency.forEach(function(id) {
           console.log(id)
}
```

Which returns `id 2 and id 3 as objects`. Is there a way to use `id.active` straight away? By using only one loop? Because the result so far are objects without any connection to the related JSON data. Would it require to loop through the whole JSON data to retrieve those values?

Comment: *"Would it require to loop through the whole JSON data to retrieve those values?"* Yes. You have to find the other objects with that ID. Of course nothing prevents you from preprocessing the data and creating an `id -> value` map first so that you can easily lookup values by ID.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON

Comment: Is this what you're asking? `thisElement.dependency.map(d => d.active )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient thing to to is create a hashmap with an Object or Map first so you only need to iterate the array once to find dependency related values.

You could do it by using `Array#find()` to search whole array each time but that is far more time complexity than the o(1) object lookup

```js
const activeMap = new Map(data.map(obj  => [obj.id, obj.active]))

data[0].dependency.forEach(({id}) => console.log(id ,'  active: ' , activeMap.get(id)))
```

```html
<script>
const data =
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "active": true,
    "dependency": [
      {"id": 2 },
      {"id": 3}
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "active": true
  }
]
</script>
```